# Modifying the transform.position of an instantiated object gives undesired values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm Trying to recreate a RTS queue of people that must interact with a drink stand.
The Method i'm implementing has a Queue object with a child FirstPosition Object; Then I want a script to Instantiate a new position in the queue when someone occupies the previous slot.
The problem is that, when taking the position of the FirstQueuePosition and trying to modify its transform.position values for the next queue slots, the values that the script is giving to the clone aren't the ones I'm giving.

Here is the code of the script (Still testing it without people):

```
public class QueueController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject QueueFirstPosition;
    public List<GameObject> Queue;
    float nextSpawn;
    public float SpawnRate;
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Time.time >= nextSpawn)
        {
            Vector3 NextQueuePosition = QueueFirstPosition.transform.position 
                + new Vector3(QueueFirstPosition.transform.position.x - 2.5f, 0 , QueueFirstPosition.transform.position.z + 2.5f);
            nextSpawn = Time.time + SpawnRate;
            var QueuePositionClone = Instantiate(QueueFirstPosition, NextQueuePosition, QueueFirstPosition.transform.rotation);
            QueuePositionClone.transform.SetParent(this.transform); 
            Queue.Add(QueuePositionClone);
            Debug.Log(QueuePositionClone.transform.position);
            QueueFirstPosition.transform.position = QueuePositionClone.transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

And these are the positions i'm getting:

[image: weirdQueueInnit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are always adding the `position` in

```
Vector3 NextQueuePosition = QueueFirstPosition.transform.position 
    + new Vector3(QueueFirstPosition.transform.position.x - 2.5f, 0, QueueFirstPosition.transform.position.z + 2.5f);
```

so the position is being incremented exponential.

I guess you rather simply wanted to do

```
Vector3 NextQueuePosition = QueueFirstPosition.transform.position 
    + new Vector3(- 2.5f, 0, + 2.5f);
```

without adding the position itself twice.

Comment: I tried that the first way around, and I changed it into what I posted here because it also gives me wrong values. The Queue is child of the drink stand, and the QueueFirstPosition is child of the queue, with a '0,0,0' position; so the next instance should be '-2.5, 0, 2.5' and this are the positions i'm getting when I do way you explained. [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/QeLNiGZ)

Comment: well it seems that your first object isn't placed at `0,0,0` but rather at `46.0, 0.2, 68.2`

Comment: Yes, sorry. The clone was taking the parent's (Queue) position, the one you gave, and it was also an addition issue. The correct amount for the queue to go the direction I wanted (according to the parent) was +2,0,0. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.